# Gradle annotation processor order (Android)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dagger-2, annotation-processing, kapt

I'm writing a library based on code generation.
This library generating dagger's module via annotations. How do I run my annotation processor before dagger's code generation?

Now it crashes on build because dagger trying to build the component before modules was generated.

Error:

```
.ktC:\Users\syncended\AndroidStudioProjects\Daggerblade\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\dev\syncended\daggerblade\AppComponent.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
@dagger.Component(modules = {BookModule.class})
                             ^
  symbol: class BookModuleC:\Users\syncended\AndroidStudioProjects\Daggerblade\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\dev\syncended\daggerblade\AppComponent.java:7: error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^Attempt to reopen a file for path C:\Users\syncended\AndroidStudioProjects\Daggerblade\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\dev\syncended\blade\BookModule.kt
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
```